# Reverse SharePoint Command

Tags: 2013, powershell, 2016, wopi

```
Get-SPWOPIBinding -Action "MobileView" -Application "WordPDF" | Remove-SPWOPIBinding -Confirm:$false
Get-SPWOPIBinding -Application "WordPDF" | Remove-SPWOPIBinding -Confirm:$false
```

Hi, I recently ran the above command on my SharePoint 2016 server, does anyone know how I can reverse the changes that it makes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't have any fancy settings configured previously, the best approach is to first disconnect SharePoint from Office Server and connect it back from scratch. So can do the following:

```
Remove-SPWOPIBinding -All:$true
```

Reconnect SharePoint to OWA by running the following. Bear in mind, that this assumes your OWA uses HTTP instead of HTTPS:

```
New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName <WacServerName> -AllowHTTP
Get-SPWOPIZone
Set-SPWOPIZone -zone "internal-http"
(Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig).AllowOAuthOverHttp
$config = (Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig)
$config.AllowOAuthOverHttp = $true
$config.Update()
```

More details in [Configure Office Online Server for SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/configure-office-online-server-for-sharepoint-server-2016/configure-office-online-server-for-sharepoint-server-2016)

Alternatively, you can try the following command:

```
New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName "Server.corp.Contoso.com"
```

> This example creates bindings for all the applications and file name
> extensions that the WOPI application supports on the current
> SharePoint farm where this cmdlet is run.

Comment: Hi, I have just tried running these commands but I am still getting "Sorry something went wrong. An error has occurred on the server" whenever I hover over a PDF in search results it only seems to be PDF's that are affected, do you have any ideas why?